Preventing ScreenShot on websites connected with acounts
After a long search I couldn't find a way to prevent screen capture (there is only drm for videos and not free).
So, Can we use gotpointercapture event because it has a pointerType property and its values could be "touch", "mouse" and "pen". Then if i get a "" this is a screen capture and not a click then i could take the right decision and restrict user account
And could you find an alternative?
Please help me, my brain is going to explode 

It seems to not be possible. Ref1 Ref2. Let's say on a PC you block print using css media query, and using js you check for if "print screen" or "Win + LShift + S" pressed make screen black until refresh, then user can open a notepad, make it small and then take ss of your webpage since the focus is on notepad.

I'm sorry, but I don't have a PC to test it I'm using only kiwi browser on Android. I have seen all these refs, what about these solutions :  `body {
opacity: 1; /* default opacity */
}
body:not(:focus) {
opacity: 0; /* hide the page when it loses focus */
}, and window.addEventListener('blur', function() {
document.body.style.opacity = 0;
});`. I have test it with split mode on android and it works!

i suggest testing on a pc, or asking a trusted peer to do so.
